# Google Sheets QUERY 'where' condition returning empty output when trying to select by date

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I am learning Google Sheets functions/formulas, and am running into an issue with the QUERY function. I have two separate sheets, and am trying to pull rows/columns from one sheet into the other. Sheet B is where I want to pull the data from. Sheet B has 5 columns, A through E. Rows are added and deleted to this sheet, so the number of rows being queried will vary. I want to pull all rows where column E equals today's date. Here is the code I'm trying:

```
=query('SheetB'!A5:E100, "SELECT A,B,D,E where E = '" &TODAY()& "'")
```

Column E is formatted as such: MM/DD/YY

This returns "#N/A", or "Query completed with an empty output"

If I run the above code without the where condition, it returns data as expected. I have no idea why, or what the problem is. Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the simplest way to do it:

```
=query('SheetB'!A5:E100, "SELECT * where E = toDate(now())")
```

Query uses a very specific date format because different regions have vastly different formats. Below is what you would use if you had specific dates.

```
=query('SheetB'!A5:E100, "SELECT A,B,D,E where E = date '"&TEXT(TODAY(),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'")
```

Notice you need to write date preceding 'yyyy-mm-dd' format.

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage

Answer (score 0):

if **E** column is a valid date it would be:

```
=QUERY({SheetB!A5:B100, SheetB!D5:E100},  
 "where Col4 = date '"&TEXT(TODAY(), "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'", 0)
```

or:

```
=QUERY('SheetB'!A5:E100, 
 "select A,B,D,E
  where E = "&DATEVALUE(TODAY()), 0)
```

Comment: I guess the only con of doing `where E = 
 toDate(now())` vs `where E = "&DATEVALUE(TODAY())` is the first one is stuck in GMT timezone but it looks cleaner.